# applescript - using conditional systems in a defined list

Tags: list, loops, applescript

Overview

- trying to use a conditional statement with a list
- how do you iterate in the list to only execute on the conditional statement when it has iterated to theItem only in that specific loop iteration.

Code:
It should say hello but it doesn't

```
set myList to {"Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
repeat with theItem in myList
    log theItem
    if theItem = "Hello" then
        say theItem
    end if
end repeat
```

but if I do this it works

```
set myList to {"Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
repeat with theItem in myList
    log theItem
    if theItem is in "Hello" then
        say theItem
    end if
end repeat
```

Is the only way to use a conditional statement is with "is in" to execute code in the conditional statement?

Comment: You can use, e.g.: `if the contents of theItem is equal to "Hello" then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script only wants to check that "hello" is in your list, you do not need a loop:

```
set myList to {"Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
if "Hello" is in myList then
    log "the list contains item 'hello'"
else
    log "no item found"
end if
```

If you still want to use a loop, probably the main reason is that you want to know the item number (?).

```
set myList to { "Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
repeat with i from 1 to count of myList
    set theItem to item i of myList
    if theItem = "Hello" then exit repeat
end repeat
log "item " & i & " is my target !!"
```

Finally, to answer to your initial question, Applescript documentation states that if the "if" checks item of a list, it must be referred as 'contents of' (see :[Apple Documentation about Repeat with](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html))
Then script bellow is also working:

```
set myList to {"Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
repeat with theItem in myList
    log theItem
    if (contents of theItem) is "Hello" then
        log "this is my item"
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `repeat with theItem in myList` loop `theItem` is actually a reference to

[image]

AppleScript dereferences the object silently on your behalf **except on an equality check**.

In this particular case you have to deference the object explicitly with `contents of`

```
set myList to {"Hello", "Goodbye", "I must be going"}
repeat with theItem in myList
    log theItem
    if contents of theItem = "Hello" then
        say theItem
    end if
end repeat
```

This doesn't affect the `repeat with i from 1 to (count myList)` syntax because `item i of myList` derefernces the object implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

if theItem as text = "Hello" then

TheItem refers to the item in the list. « Hello » is a text.